# Significato di "avere pietre al sole"

Tags: meaning, idioms, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> *Turi lo sciancato*. Vi dico che la strada è giusta. Se in passato don Napoleone è stato un po' disordinato, ora **ha** quarantanove anni e molte **pietre al sole**.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "avere pietre al sole" che appare in questo testo. Ho cercato alla voce "pietra" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ho trovato in un sito che parla di [lingua, dialetto e costumi Bolognesi](http://ilbolognese.blogspot.com/2009/07/sassi.html) un articolo riguardante le differenze dialettali tra italiano e bolognese quando si parla di sassi, macigni, pietre, mattoni etc.

> **madàn**, infine, non è affatto il “mattone”, ma la “zolla”, parola che in
>   dialetto non esiste, anche se abbiamo Zola Predosa, ma è probabile che
>   questo nome derivi dalla lingua o che un tempo esistesse “zóla” anche
>   in dialetto o che abbia altra origine! È parola maschile e si usa
>   soprattutto al plurale: madón, dove dà origine ad altri modi di dire,
>   come “avàir i madón al sàul” (essere proprietari terrieri, mentre **in
>   italiano “avere mattoni o pietre al sole” significa essere proprietari
>   di case!**), “ràmper i madón” (spaccare le zolle, come fa il contadino).
>   Una discreta confusone, nella quale tuttavia noi bolognesi ci sappiamo
>   destreggiare abbastanza bene, ma è certo che ogni volta che qualcuno,
>   parlando italiano, dice “pietra” nell’invisibile fumetto che c’è sulla
>   nostra testa appare… un mattone!

Nel passaggio da te citato si vuole indicare che se anche in passato Don Napoleone era stato un po' disordinato ora è maturo e gode di una situazione economica piuttosto agiata, essendo proprietario di case.